# Ember: binding query parameter arrays to controller properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I get how to bind [query parameters to controller properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128204/ember-binding-controller-properties-to-query-parameters) and that's working great.  But my problem now is, how to bind query parameters that are *arrays* to controller properties (that are arrays)?

Either I am not doing something right (quite likely) or this is not supported in ember.

I made a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a55f02dae35caeb7cf6a7e9a77112981?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C&route=%2Fsearch%3Ffoo%5B%5D%3D1%26foo%5B%5D%3D2%26foo%5B%5D%3D3) to demonstrate.

(Note, when the twiddle loads the url is `/search`.  You have to manually change it to: `/search?foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3` - sorry)

When the twiddle page loads, the QPs:

```
foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3
```

are correctly bound to a controller property that is an array:

```
foo: ['1','2','3']
```

But when the foo array is manipulated via the action (delete #2), ember changes the format of the array expressed as QPs to `&foo=1%2C3` aka `foo=1,3`

Which in turn changes the format of the `foo` controller property from

```
foo: ['1','3']
```

to

```
foo: '1,3'
```

Is it possible for ember to retain the parameter-array format when a QP is bound to an array?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to dig up, but it appears somewhere along the way ember changed the QP format for arrays to json.  But that's sort of a work-in-progress.  Short discussion [here](https://twitter.com/machty/status/419624738772619264?lang=en).

I was able to get a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/faa438ae5096bd3738c53237b1b23fde?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C&route=%2Fresults%3Ffoo%3D%255B%2522ray%2522%252C%2522tiley%2522%255D) working with a QP array bound to controller property.